# Notation in 'right/left moving' modes

Tags: string-theory, notation

In [Superstring Theory Vol.1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107029112) chapter 2.1 we define the general solution to the massless wave equation:
$$
X^\mu(\sigma)=X^\mu_R(\sigma^-)+X^\mu_R(\sigma^+)
$$
with $$
\sigma^- = \tau-\sigma
$$
$$
\sigma^+ = \tau+\sigma
$$
Then the derivatives are defined as$$
\partial_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\tau\pm\partial_\sigma)
$$

Then it's "easy" to see that $$
\eta_{+-} =\eta_{-+} =-\frac{1}{2}
$$
and $$
\eta_{++}=\eta_{--} = 0
$$
How can I show that those are the values of the Minkowski world-sheet metric?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? You say that it's easy to show those things, but then it seems you are asking for a derivation of them. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I used the quotation marks because it's not "easy" for me to derive those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any transformation of the coordinates $x \mapsto x' = f(x)$ transforms the metric as follows
$$
g_{\mu\nu}(x) \mapsto g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial {x'}^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial {x'}^\nu} g_{\rho\lambda}(x)\,. 
$$
For the case at hand
$$
x = (\sigma,\tau) \mapsto x' = (\tau+\sigma,\tau-\sigma)
$$
So the inverse transformation is
$$
x = \left(\tfrac12(\sigma^+ - \sigma^-),\tfrac12(\sigma^+ + \sigma^-)\right)\,.
$$
Applying the formula and using $g_{\tau\sigma} = g_{\sigma\tau} = 0$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
g'_{++} &= \left(\tfrac12\right)^2 g_{\sigma\sigma} + \left(\tfrac12\right)^2g_{\tau\tau} = \tfrac14-\tfrac14 = 0\,,\\
g'_{++} &= \left(-\tfrac12\right)^2 g_{\sigma\sigma} + \left(\tfrac12\right)^2g_{\tau\tau} = \tfrac14-\tfrac14 = 0\,,\\
g'_{-+} = g'_{+-} &= -\left(\tfrac12\right)^2 g_{\sigma\sigma} + \left(\tfrac12\right)^2g_{\tau\tau} = -\tfrac14-\tfrac14 = -\tfrac12\,.\\
\end{aligned}
$$